# Automated Testing - Sign Up

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-strategy

I'm creating the user cases for developers to set automated testing for `Sign Up`.

But I'm facing an issue at the moment. I need to test `Sign Up` with a new `phone` and `email`.

So every time the test runs the phone and email have to be new.

How can I set this without manually delete the phone and email from `Firebase` and `Database`, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your emails a timestamp that never will be the same in each execution.

Something like:

```
youruser+1541682885@domain.com
```

If you use a gmail account, you can also retrieve the email from inbox using this approach.

And you can also use timestamp converted to integer for phone numbers.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the phone number I need to delete it since I need to use Firebase White List Phone Numbers so I don't get blocked. How can I delete automatically the phone number after each signup test? API endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression keeping the format in which you want your email and random number generator of 10 digit.